# How to group strings by sequential occurrence and check for values > X in another column

Tags: python

for the following data structure, I would like to use Python to find the number of SEQUENTIAL occurrences of a pattern in column C0 >= than a threshold X, and the number of corresponding values in another column prcC0 that are >= than a threshold Y

for the example below, if thresholds X = 3 and Y is 40, then the algorithm should output. rows 2:4 for string pattern B occurring >= 3 and corresponding prcC0 values >= 40

the algorithm should scan the entire data frame for such sequential patterns.

```
Seq nMin    nUniqe  n3WJ    prc3WJ  C0  prcC0
0   s00000  482 9   172 35.68   A   1.65
1   s00001  503 10  193 38.37   A   15.33
2   s00002  415 9   221 53.25   B   44.03
3   s00003  325 10  155 47.69   B   42.99
4   s00004  429 10  175 40.79   B   43.37
```

Comment: You should write some algorithm, test it out, and ask specific question when you encounter problems you can't fix. This is too broad

Comment: What is holding this _data structure_? Is it a csv? Is it a dataframe like in `Pandas` or in `R`? More details are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df

Seq  nMin  nUniqe  n3WJ  prc3WJ C0  prcC0
0  s00000   482       9   172   35.68  A   1.65
1  s00001   503      10   193   38.37  A  15.33
2  s00002   415       9   221   53.25  B  44.03
3  s00003   325      10   155   47.69  B  42.99
4  s00004   429      10   175   40.79  B  43.37

X = 3
Y = 40
df_out = df.assign(Cond=df.prcC0 >= Y)
df_out.groupby((~df_out['Cond']).cumsum()).filter(lambda x: x.shape[0] >= X+1).query('Cond == True')
```

Output:

```
      Seq  nMin  nUniqe  n3WJ  prc3WJ C0  prcC0  Cond
2  s00002   415       9   221   53.25  B  44.03  True
3  s00003   325      10   155   47.69  B  42.99  True
4  s00004   429      10   175   40.79  B  43.37  True
```